# Getting error "The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server." but not using this flag

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, sql-server-express

I recently upgraded a SQL Server Express database I was using locally to SQL Server 2012 Developer. I started getting this error. A quick search pulls up tons of posts where the answer seems to be to remove `User Instance=True;` from your connection strings.

I checked and none of my connection strings have this flag. I tried searching the entire solution for "user instance" just to make double sure and it doesn't show up anywhere. Doubly weird is that I don't get this error right away. The first couple calls to the database work...

Has anyone else had a similar experience?

Here is the exact code that is causing my error:

```
public class BetterAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var roleList = Roles.Split(',');

        //if the user is in one of the roles in the list
        foreach (string r in roleList)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //The error is consistently thrown here the second time this line
                //executes...
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(r.Trim()))
                {
```

Here are the config sections I thought were relevant:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="BioSphereContext" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="Server=fake;Database=fake;User ID=fake;Password=fake;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
</connectionStrings>

.
.
.

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>


.
.
.

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
        type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
       <parameters>
          <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
       </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Some more details about my project in case it helps...

- VS 2012
- Entity Framework 5
- Azure SDK 2.0
- ASP.NET MVC 3
- .net 4.5

Comment: Can you add your connection strings / configuration (even if you're fairly sure they're correct?)

Comment: After doing some more research I feel like this error may have something to do with DefaultSessionProvider.  Does that ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong, but I deleted and re-cloned my git repository. Error went away.... never getting that day back... lol.  I'll leave the post in case any of this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses ASP.NET Membership Roles Provider

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(r.Trim()))
```

The machine.config shows

```
            <roleManager>
            <providers>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
```

Pointing to "LocalSqlServer" in the same file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

There is the User Instance.

TODO: Configure your roleManager to use either another roles provider or the AspNetSqlRoleProvider to use a different connection string.

same goes for session (What is DefaultConnection? i don't see a connection string named like this), membership and profile.

So try:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         connectionStringName="BioSphereContext" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: I don't have machine.config and my web.config doesn't have a roleManager. That said I think I see how it applies to the context of my app.  I tried setting the connection on my session state provider to BiosphereContext as you suggested, had no affect.  I tried commenting out the entire session state block, still get same error at same line.  So now I'm wondering if this really doesn't have anything to do with it.  Only way i've got the message to change is to remove aspnetdb.mdf from app_data folder.  then i get "can't connect to database" with inner exception about user instance flag... bah

Comment: Sure you have a machine.config (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config)