# ASP.NET Configuration Tool in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to enter the security tab of ASP.NET Configuration in Visual Studio 2010.  The database aspnetdb has been installed in the SQL server and added to the App_Data folder of the project. When trying to open the security tab this is the error message:

> The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.

Thanks

Comment: @luke2012 I'm guessing you didn't actually look at those results.  There is some significance to the context of an error message.  Let's look at the first result where the accepted answer is a self answer where they say "I deleted and re-cloned my git repository. Error went away".  Does that sound like it applies to this scenario?

Comment: @AaronLS I did actually look at those results and unless you are seeing a different set of results than me then you are crazy. First result from stackoverflow and the second basically say the same thing... 'User Instances are a Sql Server Express only feature.'

Comment: @luke2012 http://stackoverflow.com/q/17262042/84206

Comment: @AaronLS of course there is duplicate questions to this that's why I said do a Google search to find his answer then he can close his question. Your presence here is not needed.

Comment: @luke2012 Telling people to use Google is what is not needed. There is a reason there isn't a close reason for "Can be found via Google".  We are building content here.  It's presence via Google does not preclude it from being including on SO.  If your intent is to direct someone to another question that answers their question, then there is a duplicate close vote for that reason.

Comment: @AaronLS the person asking the question should at least do a basic search first before asking. I was alluding to the fact that his answer could be so easily found on Google that the question probably shouldn't have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @luke2012 There are close reasons that covers every scenario in which "the question shouldn't have been asked in the first place".  If that is your belief, then you should use the appropriate close reason.  In this case it will provide verifiable evidence of your belief that another question addresses this specific scenario.  Otherwise it is just a soup of results from various scenarios that generate the same error.